Video Input does NOT work in React Native Expo WebView for Android. How do I fix it?
I have a WebView in my React Native Expo app. Image and video inputs do not work in the Android app. If I go to the web page in an Android web browser, the inputs work and the camera opens. But inside of the Expo app, it does NOT work on Android.
Here is the React Native Expo WebView code:
<WebView 
   userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.1; Galaxy Nexus Build/JRO03C) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19"
   key={webViewKey} 
   style={styles.webview}
   source={{ uri: url }}
   javaScriptEnabled={true}
   domStorageEnabled={true}
   thirdPartyCookiesEnabled={true}
   sharedCookiesEnabled={true}
   cacheEnabled={true}
   incognito={false}
   allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
   mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
   originWhitelist={['*']}
   onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={handleNavigation}
/>

On one of the pages in the URL being displayed, there are image and video inputs. Here is the React website code:
<div>
   <label htmlFor={"file-upload1"} className="btn btn-sm bg-white shadow-none text-[#1da1f2]">
      <AddPhotoAlternateIcon fontSize='medium' /> 
      <p className='text-gray-700'>Image</p>
   </label>
   <input 
      id={"file-upload1"} 
      type="file" 
      className='hidden' 
      onChange={handleFileUpload} 
      accept='image/*'
   />
</div>
<div>
   <label htmlFor={"video-upload"} className="btn btn-sm bg-white shadow-none text-[#1da1f2]">
      <VideoCallIcon fontSize='medium' />
      <p className='text-gray-700'>Short Video</p>
   </label>
   <input 
      id={"video-upload"} 
      type="file" 
      className='hidden' 
      onChange={handleFileUpload} 
      accept='video/*'
      capture='user'
   />
</div>

These file inputs just don't work inside of the Android Expo app. They work everywhere else, including in the iOS app.
Here is the android part of my app.json file:
"android": {
   "adaptiveIcon": {
      "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
   },
   "package": "my.package.name",
   "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
   "versionCode": 19,
   "permissions": [
     "CAMERA",
     "RECORD_AUDIO"
   ]
},

How do I get the inputs to work in the Android Expo app?
